# AEM Content Fragment fields values does not sent for translation

Tags: aem, translation

I tried to translate the Content Fragment content but that content is not sent for translation.

Let's take an example, suppose, we have a Content fragment model, named "Press Release" and there are 2 fields "title" and "description". Once we create a content fragment based on the "Press Release" model and Create a Translation project then content fragment fields are not going for translation,

I am using AEM 6.5.12.0 version,

I tried to add some translation rules but that also does not help, I am sure there are some issues with writing a Translation rule for translating against the Content Fragment Model.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First did you create the target language folder in the assets? it is necessary for AEM to know where it needs to create the target.
[Assets language structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZnGB.png)

How do you add translation rules?
for title and description the properties in translation config UI should be: jcr:title and jcr:description

[Translation config UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT1eS.png)

Check this file in the CRXde  /conf/global/settings/translation/rules/translation_rules.xml that:

- is at after
- you have those 2 properties under content/dam

hope it will help
Seb